# How do I fix Intercom REST API pagination with starting_after parameter?

Tags: api, pagination

I have a following json configuration for extracting data from Intercom API.

About pagination: https://developers.intercom.com/building-apps/docs/pagination-cursor
About endpoint: https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/reference/listconversations

The pagination should work with params "starting_after" from the previous request response.

```
{
 "parameters": {
  "api": {
   "baseUrl": "https://api.intercom.io/",
   "pagination": {
    "method": "cursor",
    "idKey": "pages.next.starting_after",
    "param": "starting_after",
    "increment": 1
   }
  },
  "config": {
   "outputBucket": "ge-tutorial",
   "debug": true,
   "jobs": [
    {
     "endpoint": "conversations",
     "params": {
      "per_page": 20
     },
     "headers": {
      "Intercom-Version": "2.9",
      "accept": "application/json",
      "authorization": "Bearer aaaa"
     }
    }
   ]
  },
  "incrementalOutput": true
 }
}
```

Error: [2023-05-25T08:42:31.006624+00:00] logger.ERROR: Cursor value 'null' is not numeric. [] []"